# Perform count on distinct values of a bag in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a question on Pig when performing what seems like two levels of groupings.  As an example, let's say I had some example input data like:

```
email_id:chararray    from:chararray        to:bag{recipients:tuple(recipient:chararray)}
e1                    user1@example.com     {(friend1@example.com),(friend2@example.com),(friend3@myusers.com)}
e2                    user1@example.com     {(friend1@example.com),(friend4@example.com)}
e3                    user1@example.com     {(friend5@example.com)}
e4                    user2@example.com     {(friend2@example.com),(friend4@example.com)}
```

So each line is an email from a user "from" to user(s) "to".

And I ultimately want a list of all senders and all the people they've sent emails to, including the # of emails sent for each person, sorted from highest to lowest, for example:

```
user1@example.com     {(friend1@example.com, 2), (friend2@example.com, 1), (friend3@example.com, 1), (friend4@example.com, 1), (friend5@example.com, 1)}
user2@example.com     {(friend2@example.com, 1), (friend4@example.com, 1)}
```

Ideas on the best way to tackle this in Pig would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one version of the script:

```
inpt = load '/pig_data/pig_fun/input/from_senders.txt' as (email_id:chararray, from:chararray, to:bag{recipients:tuple(recipient:chararray)});

pivot = foreach inpt generate from, FLATTEN(to);
pivot = foreach pivot generate from, to::recipient as recipient;
dump pivot;
/*
(user1@example.com,friend1@example.com)
(user1@example.com,friend2@example.com)
(user1@example.com,friend3@myusers.com)
(user1@example.com,friend1@example.com)
(user1@example.com,friend4@example.com)
(user1@example.com,friend5@example.com)
(user2@example.com,friend2@example.com)
(user2@example.com,friend4@example.com)
*/

grp = group pivot by (from, recipient);
with_count = foreach grp generate FLATTEN(group), COUNT(pivot) as count;
dump with_count;
/*
(user1@example.com,friend1@example.com,2)
(user1@example.com,friend2@example.com,1)
(user1@example.com,friend3@myusers.com,1)
(user1@example.com,friend4@example.com,1)
(user1@example.com,friend5@example.com,1)
(user2@example.com,friend2@example.com,1)
(user2@example.com,friend4@example.com,1)
*/

to_bag = group with_count by from;
result = foreach to_bag {
    order_by_count = order with_count by count desc;
    generate group as from, order_by_count.(recipient, count);
};
dump result;
/*
(user1@example.com,{(friend1@example.com,2),(friend2@example.com,1),(friend3@myusers.com,1),(friend4@example.com,1),(friend5@example.com,1)})
(user2@example.com,{(friend2@example.com,1),(friend4@example.com,1)})
*/
```

Hope it helps.